# Flutter-> TextField hidden by KeyBoard

Tags: flutter, keyboard, autoscroll

i have a problem, when i'm focusing on a TextFormField, my keyBoard come over this one. I have tried so much differents ways. 
I have found one single solution but my view begin from the bottom to the top and i want the opposite.
I hope someone got a solution to auto scroll the TextFormField, thank you !

My code here :

````
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nomController.dispose();
    adresseController.dispose();
    complementAdresseController.dispose();
    villeController.dispose();
    codePostalController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //controller for get value from TextFormField
  TextEditingController nomController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController adresseController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController complementAdresseController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController villeController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController codePostalController = TextEditingController();

  //save value in variables for send data from http request
  String nom;
  String adresse;
  String complement;
  String ville;
  String codePostal;

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  sendFormData() async {
    var postUri = Uri.parse("http://51.158.67.16:8000/api/contact/");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    request.fields['name'] = nom;
    request.fields['adresse'] = adresse;
    request.fields['complement'] = complement;
    request.fields['city'] = ville;
    request.fields['postalCode'] = codePostal;

    print(nom);
    print(adresse);
    print(complement);
    print(ville);
    print(codePostal);

    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        print("Uploaded!");
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    });
  }

  validateAndSave() async {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        nom = nomController.text;
        adresse = adresseController.text;
        complement = complementAdresseController.text;
        ville = villeController.text;
        codePostal = codePostalController.text;
      });

      await sendFormData();
    } else {
      print('form is invalid');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            child: Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(22, 22, 22, 1.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Veuillez remplir les champs si dessous afin de nous communiquer l\'emplacement et le nom du monument ou de l\'oeuvre',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Nom de l’oeuvre",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                            child: new TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              controller: nomController,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  nom = value;
                                });
                              },
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.length <= 4) {
                                  showDialog(
                                      barrierDismissible: false,
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                            titleTextStyle:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                            title: Text(
                                                "Le nom doit contenir au minimum 4 lettres"),
                                            actions: <Widget>[
                                              FlatButton(
                                                onPressed: () =>
                                                    Navigator.pop(context),
                                                child: Text('OK',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 18,
                                                        color: Colors.white)),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ));
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                      fontSize: 16),
                                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                                  hintText: 'Nom du monument, oeuvre...',
                                  fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                  filled: true,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Adresse",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              controller: adresseController,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  adresse = value;
                                });
                              },
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                      fontSize: 16),
                                  suffixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.search,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: '( Optionnel ) Adresse',
                                  fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                  filled: true,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Complément d'adresse",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              controller: complementAdresseController,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  complement = value;
                                });
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                      fontSize: 16),
                                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                                  hintText: '(Optionnel) Complement d’adresse',
                                  fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                  filled: true,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Ville",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(10.0))),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  controller: villeController,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      ville = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.length <= 2) {
                                      showDialog(
                                          barrierDismissible: false,
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      Color.fromRGBO(
                                                          40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white),
                                                  title: Text(
                                                      "La ville doit contenir au minimum 2 lettres"),
                                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                                    FlatButton(
                                                      onPressed: () =>
                                                          Navigator.pop(
                                                              context),
                                                      child: Text('OK',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 18,
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .white)),
                                                    )
                                                  ]));
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                              133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                          fontSize: 16),
                                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                              133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                                      hintText: 'Ville',
                                      fillColor:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                      filled: true,
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      )),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Code Postal",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(10.0))),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  controller: codePostalController,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      codePostal = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.length != 5) {
                                      showDialog(
                                          barrierDismissible: false,
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      Color.fromRGBO(
                                                          40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white),
                                                  title: Text(
                                                      "Le code postal doit contenir 5 chiffres"),
                                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                                    FlatButton(
                                                      onPressed: () =>
                                                          Navigator.pop(
                                                              context),
                                                      child: Text('OK',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 18,
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .white)),
                                                    )
                                                  ]));
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                        fontSize: 16),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    ),
                                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                                    hintText: 'Code postal',
                                    fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                    filled: true,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                          FlatButton(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await validateAndSave();
                              },
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 60),
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                  height: 65,
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(243, 243, 243, 1.0)),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'ENVOYER',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0)),
                                  ),

                                  //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 53, 0, 20),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ))
                ]))));
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Your page should contain `Scaffold` widget to get the auto scroll feature.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: Scaffold(body: MyPage()),  //TODO: Add Scaffold
   );
 }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   nomController.dispose();
   adresseController.dispose();
   complementAdresseController.dispose();
   villeController.dispose();
   codePostalController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }

 //controller for get value from TextFormField
 TextEditingController nomController = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController adresseController = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController complementAdresseController = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController villeController = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController codePostalController = TextEditingController();

 //save value in variables for send data from http request
 String nom;
 String adresse;
 String complement;
 String ville;
 String codePostal;

 final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

 sendFormData() async {
   var postUri = Uri.parse("http://51.158.67.16:8000/api/contact/");
   var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
   request.fields['name'] = nom;
   request.fields['adresse'] = adresse;
   request.fields['complement'] = complement;
   request.fields['city'] = ville;
   request.fields['postalCode'] = codePostal;

   print(nom);
   print(adresse);
   print(complement);
   print(ville);
   print(codePostal);

   request.send().then((response) {
     if (response.statusCode == 201) {
       print("Uploaded!");
     } else {
       print(response.statusCode);
     }
   });
 }

 validateAndSave() async {
   final form = _formKey.currentState;
   if (form.validate()) {
     setState(() {
       nom = nomController.text;
       adresse = adresseController.text;
       complement = complementAdresseController.text;
       ville = villeController.text;
       codePostal = codePostalController.text;
     });

     await sendFormData();
   } else {
     print('form is invalid');
   }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SingleChildScrollView(
     child: SafeArea(
       top: false,
       bottom: false,
       child: Container(
         color: Color.fromRGBO(22, 22, 22, 1.0),
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0),
               child: Text(
                 'Veuillez remplir les champs si dessous afin de nous communiquer l\'emplacement et le nom du monument ou de l\'oeuvre',
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                 style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.white,
                   fontSize: 16,
                   fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             Form(
               key: _formKey,
               child: Column(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                         child: Text(
                           "Nom de l’oeuvre",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                         ),
                       )),
                   Container(
                     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius:
                             BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                     child: new TextFormField(
                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                       controller: nomController,
                       onChanged: (value) {
                         setState(() {
                           nom = value;
                         });
                       },
                       validator: (value) {
                         if (value.length <= 4) {
                           showDialog(
                               barrierDismissible: false,
                               context: context,
                               builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                     backgroundColor:
                                         Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                     titleTextStyle:
                                         TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                     title: Text(
                                         "Le nom doit contenir au minimum 4 lettres"),
                                     actions: <Widget>[
                                       FlatButton(
                                         onPressed: () =>
                                             Navigator.pop(context),
                                         child: Text('OK',
                                             style: TextStyle(
                                                 fontSize: 18,
                                                 color: Colors.white)),
                                       )
                                     ],
                                   ));
                         }
                         return null;
                       },
                       textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                               vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                           hintStyle: TextStyle(
                               color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                               fontSize: 16),
                           suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                               color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                           hintText: 'Nom du monument, oeuvre...',
                           fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                           filled: true,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                             borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                           )),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                         child: Text(
                           "Adresse",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                         ),
                       )),
                   Container(
                     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius:
                             BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                     child: TextFormField(
                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                       controller: adresseController,
                       onChanged: (value) {
                         setState(() {
                           adresse = value;
                         });
                       },
                       textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                               vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                           hintStyle: TextStyle(
                               color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                               fontSize: 16),
                           suffixIcon: Icon(
                             Icons.search,
                             color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                           ),
                           hintText: '( Optionnel ) Adresse',
                           fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                           filled: true,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                             borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                           )),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                         child: Text(
                           "Complément d'adresse",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                         ),
                       )),
                   Container(
                     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius:
                             BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                     child: TextFormField(
                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                       controller: complementAdresseController,
                       onChanged: (value) {
                         setState(() {
                           complement = value;
                         });
                       },
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                               vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                           hintStyle: TextStyle(
                               color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                               fontSize: 16),
                           suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                               color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                           hintText: '(Optionnel) Complement d’adresse',
                           fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                           filled: true,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                             borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                           )),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                         child: Text(
                           "Ville",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                         ),
                       )),
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Container(
                         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                         child: TextFormField(
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                           controller: villeController,
                           onChanged: (value) {
                             setState(() {
                               ville = value;
                             });
                           },
                           validator: (value) {
                             if (value.length <= 2) {
                               showDialog(
                                   barrierDismissible: false,
                                   context: context,
                                   builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                           backgroundColor:
                                               Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                           titleTextStyle:
                                               TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                           title: Text(
                                               "La ville doit contenir au minimum 2 lettres"),
                                           actions: <Widget>[
                                             FlatButton(
                                               onPressed: () =>
                                                   Navigator.pop(context),
                                               child: Text('OK',
                                                   style: TextStyle(
                                                       fontSize: 18,
                                                       color: Colors.white)),
                                             )
                                           ]));
                             }
                             return null;
                           },
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                               contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                   vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                               hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                   fontSize: 16),
                               suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                   color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                               hintText: 'Ville',
                               fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                               filled: true,
                               border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                 borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                               )),
                         ),
                       )),
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 22, 0, 4),
                         child: Text(
                           "Code Postal",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                         ),
                       )),
                   Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: Container(
                         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
                         child: TextFormField(
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                           controller: codePostalController,
                           onChanged: (value) {
                             setState(() {
                               codePostal = value;
                             });
                           },
                           validator: (value) {
                             if (value.length != 5) {
                               showDialog(
                                   barrierDismissible: false,
                                   context: context,
                                   builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                           backgroundColor:
                                               Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                                           titleTextStyle:
                                               TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                           title: Text(
                                               "Le code postal doit contenir 5 chiffres"),
                                           actions: <Widget>[
                                             FlatButton(
                                               onPressed: () =>
                                                   Navigator.pop(context),
                                               child: Text('OK',
                                                   style: TextStyle(
                                                       fontSize: 18,
                                                       color: Colors.white)),
                                             )
                                           ]));
                             }
                             return null;
                           },
                           keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                             contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                 vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                             hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                 color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0),
                                 fontSize: 16),
                             border: OutlineInputBorder(
                               borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                             ),
                             suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                 color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 133, 133, 1.0)),
                             hintText: 'Code postal',
                             fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                             filled: true,
                           ),
                         ),
                       )),
                   FlatButton(
                     color: Colors.transparent,
                     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                     onPressed: () async {
                       await validateAndSave();
                     },
                     textColor: Colors.white,
                     child: Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 60),
                       child: Container(
                         alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                         height: 65,
                         decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                             color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 243, 243, 1.0)),
                         child: Text(
                           'ENVOYER',
                           style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 18,
                               color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0)),
                         ),
                         //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 53, 0, 20),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             )
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already got a scaffold on my main, i change my widget when icon was clicked on my bottom Navigation bar

my main here:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:device_id/device_id.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:projet_malvoyant/userScreen.dart';
import 'package:statusbar/statusbar.dart';
import 'downloadScreen.dart';
import 'homePageScreen.dart';
import 'contactScreen.dart';
import 'appBar/contactAppBar.dart';
import 'appBar/downloadAppBar.dart';
import 'device_id.dart';

HomePageScreenState accessLocation;
Timer timer;

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
  //timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => accessLocation.getOeuvreThemeFromLocation());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  Color color = Color.fromRGBO(155, 155, 155, 1.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    StatusBar.color(Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0));
    // Device_id.main();

    Widget content;
    Widget contentAppBar;

    switch (_selectedPage) {
      case 0:
        content = HomePageScreen();

        //contentAppBar = HomePageAppBar();

        break;
      case 1:
        content = DownloadScreen();
        contentAppBar = DownloadAppBar();

        break;
      case 2:
        content = ContactScreen();
        contentAppBar = ContactAppBar();

        break;
      case 3:
        content = UserScreen();

        break;
    }

    return MaterialApp(
        title: '',
        home: Scaffold(

            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(22, 22, 22, 1.0),
            appBar: contentAppBar,
            body: content,
            bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar(context)));
  }

  Widget bottomNavBar(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _selectedPage,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedPage = index;
        });
      },
      iconSize: 24.0,
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
              IconData(
                67,
                fontFamily: 'Glyphter',
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 27),
          title: Text('Accueil'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                IconData(
                  66,
                  fontFamily: 'Glyphter',
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 27),
            title: Text('Téléchargement')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              IconData(
                68,
                fontFamily: 'Glyphter',
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 27,
            ),
            title: Text(
              '',
            )),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                IconData(
                  65,
                  fontFamily: 'Glyphter',
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 27),
            title: Text('Courriel')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Add this line "resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true," to your Scaffold and put your main container in ScrollView.

```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
   key: _scaffoldKey,
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   body: SingleChildScrollView(    
      child: Container()
   ),
  );
 }
```